# Speeding up Parallel.ForEach iterating through datatable and rendering crystal report as byte stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel.foreach

Good day,

I am attempting to speed up the processing of 5000 rows received from the database, render as a crystal report, export to byte stream and then save that byte stream in a database table.
Currently I am using parallel.ForEach on a datatable. This uses 40 parallel processes that then sequentially iterates 125 (i.e 5000/40) records of the 5000 rows.  It take approximately 5 minutes to do 5000 at the moment. Please assist on any suggestions on how to speed this up.

```
DataTable dtBills = new DataTable("dtBills");//I used an OdbcDataAdapter to fill this with 5000 records

private void ParallelProcess()
        {
            int numbills = 5000;
            int numprocesses = 40;
            int numsequential = numbills / numprocesses;

            int p=0;

            if (numbills < numprocesses)
                p = numbills;
            else
                p = numprocesses;

            Parallel.For(1, p+1, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 40 }, i =>
            {
                SequentialProcess(numsequential,i);

            });

        }

        private void SequentialProcess(int batch,int num)
        {
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "Bill.rpt");

            foreach(DataRow drow in dtBills.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Skip((num - 1) * batch).Take(batch).CopyToDataTable().Rows)

            {

                cryRpt.SetParameterValue(..... //here I set Crystal report Parameter values

                Stream stream = cryRpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                byte[] contents = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(contents, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                stream.Close();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sconnstr))
                {
                    using (SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(sconnstr))
                    {

                        String qry = @"INSERT INTO ....."
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, sconn))
                        {

                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(// Set values for insert here one of which will be contents

                            cmd.Connection = sconn;

                            sconn.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            sconn.Close();

                        }


                    }
                }

            }

            cryRpt.Close();
            cryRpt.Dispose();

        }
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you implemented it first as a non-parallel process? How do you know this way of working is faster?

Comment: Running DB calls in parallel isn't going to help much. Create a stored procedure with table value parameter and pass the datatable at once, inside the SP insert all the rows. In client side just call that SP with `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`.

Comment: Hi Roy Dictus For the last couple of weeks I have been trying to optimize this process. It started off at 111 minutes for 5000 records where the reprt had 3 subreports. Without the parallel processing it takes about 40mins. Now with parallel processing I am down to 5mins.

Comment: Hi Sriram Sakthivel, I will try your suggestion . Thanks. The only thing is the time it will take to build up this new datatable to then pass it may be slow. But i will still try it. Thanks